# SELECT data as August, 2019 from datetime input and group by it

Tags: mysql, sql

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════╗
║        id  price   user    stamp        ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 14  650.00  123     2020-06-15 13:34:59 ║
║ 14  650.00  123     2020-07-15 13:34:59 ║
║ 14  650.00  123     2020-08-15 13:34:59 ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I have this, and I know the FROM_UNIXTIME is wrong, but I cannot find similar for a datetime stamp.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`stamp`, '%M, %Y') AS `date`,
        SUM(`press`.`id`) AS `count`
        FROM `press` GROUP BY `date` ORDER BY `stamp`
```

And I want to have a response like this

```
[date] => April, 2020
[0] => April, 2020
[count] => 11
[1] => 11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`stamp`, '%M, %Y') AS `date`,
      SUM(`press`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `press`
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `stamp`
```